# SAT Geometry Find length of Chord inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLJpT.jpg

The answer: A. I'm really not sure where to start. I did find a formula online for finding the length of a chord if given a central angle:
$2c=2r\sin \frac{θ}{2}$.

Source: https://www.ck12.org/trigonometry/Length-of-a-Chord/lesson/Length-of-a-Chord-TRIG/

However, I would not have been able to come up with that equation myself. Is there another intuitive solution to this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$QR=r$ because if $\measuredangle QOR=\alpha$ then $\alpha+2\alpha=180^{\circ}$,

which gives $\measuredangle QOR=60^{\circ}$ and $\Delta QOR$ is equilateral triangle.

Id est, $QR=OR=OQ=r$.

Comment: thank you. Makes sense.

Comment: @Arcuvia You are welcome!